# Multiple Source Folder within a single eclipse project using MAVEN

Tags: maven-2

I wanted to create multi source folders using MAVEN

project/src/main/java/persistence
project/src/main/java/business
project/src/main/java/presentation

Then target folder structure should be:
target/classes/persistence
project/src/main/java/business
project/src/main/java/presentation

I searched this question in stackoverflow. But I couldn't figure out the solution.

I tried with 'build-helper-maven-plugin'. But No luck.

```
                       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/java/persistence</source>
                    <source>src/main/java/business</source>
                    <source>src/main/java/presentation</source>
                    <source>src/main/java/systemutil</source>
                    <source>src/main/java/service</source>
                </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>            </executions>
```

Any help?

Comment: Why would you like to have multiple sources? It sound like an misunderstanding of Maven concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Java files in the configured folders should be compiled by maven. But all these compilations are taken to the classes folder itself. So multi source folders are possible but multi output is not possible with the build-helper-maven-plugin.